# "Pinch to zoom" gesture with Focaltech touchpad in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: touchpad, zooming, focaltech

I havce a problem with the geasture of my touchpad for example the pinch to zoom does not work.
I tried to run this `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms`
and this: `apt-get update`
but i have this error:

```
w: impossible recuperare Http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms/ubuntu/dists/willy/main/binary-i386/packages 404 not fount
E: impossibile scaricare alcuni file di indice: saranno ignorati o verranno usati quelli vecchi.
```

Please someone can help me?

Best regards

```
xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ FocalTechPS/2 FocalTech FocalTech Touchpad    id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]

dmesg | grep pnp
[    0.182046] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.182245] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs FLT0102 SYN0a00 SYN0002 PNP0f03 PNP0f13 PNP0f12 (active)
[    0.182271] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs ATK3001 PNP030b (active)
[    0.182375] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.183350] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 8 devices
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput; dmesg | grep pnp` terminal command.

Comment: And pinch to zoom is not supported in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to install any drivers for Focaltech touchpads if you use kernels 4.1+.

That is why there is no package for Ubuntu 15.10 in `focaltech-dkms` PPA.

Your touchpad is fully supported and works OK. You do not need to do anything.

"Pinch to zoom" gesture is not implemented in unity desktop environment that is used in Ubuntu.

Comment: So there are no way to use it? Do you think in future updates?

Comment: Maybe some other desktop environments support it. The gesture is supported by `libinput` but it should be supported by programs too.

Comment: So not also in the future update. Do you know if gnome support it? what's libinput? thank you for your time

Comment: Gnome does not support it either. You can search the web regarding libinput. But just installing libinput will not change anything.